# CSS nth-child misses element

Tags: html, css

Seems like css nth-child missed its target, any thoughts?

[jsFiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/9HhXf/1/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#">red</a>
<br />
<a href="#">none</a>
<br />
<a href="#">gray</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:nth-child(1) {
    color:red;
}
a:nth-child(3) {
    color:gray;
}
```

Comment: The `<br />` counts as a child too. I would say this is at least a little bit unexpected.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) instead of [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) , it will work perfectly if you are removed the `<br/>` tag , because as @FritsvanCampen comment it counts as a child

```
a:nth-of-type(1) {
    color:red;
}
a:nth-of-type(3) {
    color:gray;
}
```

for better understanding refer : http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/9HhXf/2/)</kbd>

Comment: +1 for using `:nth-of-type`, however you should probably explain things like why `nth-child` didn't work, and what kind of browser compatibility you can expect from `:nth-of-type`.